# Как сделать так, чтобы в зависимости, от сочетания букв в строке, выстраивалась численная последовательность?

Tags: java, строки

Допустим есть строка String str = "книгаручкаластиккарандаш";
Как сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от наличия и порядка этих слов в строке, в численной переменной (к примеру doble a) возникала последовательность числе.
Например, слову книга должно соответствовать число 6, слову ручка число 3, ластик 2, карандаш 9.
То есть в данном случае последовательность будет 6329.
Если бы строка была бы str = "ручкакнигакарандашластик";, последовательность d была бы 3692 и т.д.

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("ручка", "3").replaceAll("карандаш", "9")
.replaceAll("книга", "6").replaceAll("ластик", "2");` и еще 10000 способов

Answer (score 0):

Для хранения последовательности можно использовать не `double`, а `String` переменную.
Предположу, что есть 2 глобальные `String` переменные: `str` и `numbers`. Можно написать метод для проверки, есть ли слово в строке, и присваивания значения в последовательность:

```
public void checkOnWord(String word, int num) {
   if(str.contains(word))
     numbers += num;
}
```

Потом из любого метода можно вызывать этот метод, передавая ему искомое слово + число, которое надо прибавить к последовательности:

```
checkOnWord("книга", 1);
checkOnWord("ручка", 5);
checkOnWord("карандаш", 3);
```

В конце, если нужна последовательность в числовой переменной, можно спарсить `String` в `int`: `int i = Integer.parseInt(numbers)`.

Comment: проблема в том, что новая строка создаёт номера в соответсвии с порядком передаваемых значения, а не порядком местонахождения слов в строке str, то есть если последовательность слов в строке str поменять на "ручкакнигакарандашластик", последовательность чисел не поменяется